# How to implement get_template_names() function in CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two list views for a same model I want to specify template for one view using get_template_names() function, But cannot resolve how to perform this...

This is my two views look like:

```
class bloglistview(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Blog


def get_queryset(self):
    return Blog.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).order_by('id')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(bloglistview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    context['categories_list'] = categories.objects.all()
    return context

class allbloglistview(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Blog

def get_queryset(self):
    return Blog.objects.all().order_by('id')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(allbloglistview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    context['categories_list'] = categories.objects.all()
    return context
```

Can Anybody help me out on this?

Comment: Why not just specify the `template_name` attributee in the classes?

Comment: Currently it is however unclear to me what you mean with "*want to specify template for one view using `get_template_names()`*"? What is not working?

Comment: set template_name attribut of class base view to the template path you want to use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the template name *depends* on certain parameters (URL parameters, `GET` parameters, `POST` parameters, `COOKIES`, etc.) you can just specify the `template_name` attribute, like:

```
class bloglistview(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    model = Blog
    template_name = 'my_fancy_template.hmtl'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).order_by('id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(bloglistview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        context['categories_list'] = categories.objects.all()
        return context
```

In case the template is resolved *dynamically* (as in depending on some URL parameters, or other parameters), you can override the `get_template_names` function that should return a *list* of strings: the name of templates that are searched in that order. For example:

```
class bloglistview(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    model = Blog

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.COOKIES.get('mom'):  # a certain check
            return ['true_template.html']
         else:
            return ['first_template.html', 'second_template.html']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).order_by('id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(bloglistview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        context['categories_list'] = categories.objects.all()
        return context
```

But as you probably see yourself, this is more complicated, and hence should only be used if the template name depends on the "context".

The [**`get_template`** function [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/template/loader.py#L5) will determine which template to use. In case the first template does not exists, then the next one will be tried until the function finds a template.